# How to Enable/Disable one item in ListView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have a below ListView in my WPF app

View:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" Width="auto" Margin="0 20" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMiningModule}" ItemsSource="{Binding MiningModules}" MouseDoubleClick="AssignMiningModule_MouseDoubleClick">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView >
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Module">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

I am trying to enable/disable one list item based on binding. I tried adding `IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected}"` to `TextBlock` as well but neither works...

Binding isn't a problem as if I just do `IsEnabled="False"` then still all items are enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure the container and not the content:

```xml
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}">
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Top man! Worked like a charm. I had to change binding as my `IsSelected` was a property in ViewModel not property of ListView as you assumed. Great, thanks!